# Iterate FormArray whilst getting index

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I can't find a way to retrieve the index in a FormArray for loop

```
for (let formElementRegistry of this.formElementRegistry().controls) {
  const formElementConfigurationGroup = formElementRegistry.get('formElementConfiguration') as FormGroup;
  const formElementId = formElementRegistry.get('formElement')?.get('id')?.value;

  const newFormElementRegistry = new FormGroup({
    formElement: new FormControl(formElementId),
    formElementConfiguration: formElementConfigurationGroup
  })

  this.formElementRegistry().removeAt(0);
  this.formElementRegistry().push(newFormElementRegistry);
}
```

There doesn't seem to be anything available within the loop from `formElementRegistry` that will give me index access

I could start a manual counter, `let i = 0;` (for example) and increment on each loop but it seems that there should be something available for me to use already

I expected that:
`for (let [index, formElementRegistry] of this.formElementRegistry().controls) {`

or `for (let {index, formElementRegistry} of this.formElementRegistry().controls) {`

might work but I am met with errors if I try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For..of loop does not provide index. If you need index, better to use simple `for` loop:

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.formElementRegistry().controls.length; i++) {
  const formElementRegistry = this.formElementRegistry().controls[i];
  ...
}
```

Comment: A small modification that should be made to the for - `for (let i = 0; i < this.formElementRegistry().controls.length; i++) {`


Notice the semi colon after `this.formElementRegistry().controls.length` instead of comma. I'm sure it's just a typo at your end